# Searching a text from a paragraph - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search

I have written the below code to search my name from a paragraph,

```
 /*jshint multistr:true */

text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Elic \
blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

var myName = "Eric";
var hits = [];
var l=0;
var count=0;


// Look for "E" in the text
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === "E") {

        for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
           for(var k =1; k < 4; k++) {
            if(text[i+k] === myName[k]){

            hits.push(text[j]); 
            }
                else {
                    break;
                }

                }           
            }

        }
    }



if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

But the output is coming like
 `[ 'E',
  'E',
  'E',
  'r',
  'r',
  'r',
  'i',
  'i',
  'i',
  'c',
  'c',
  'c',
  'E',
  'E',
  'E',
  'r',
  'r',
  'r',
  'i',
  'i',
  'i',
  'c',
  'c',
  'c',
  'E',
  'E',
  'E',
  'r',
  'r',
  'r',
  'i',
  'i',
  'i',
  'c',
  'c',
  'c' ]`

I am sure this is because of the 3rd for loop, Please give some suggestion to fine tune this code so that the output will be like,

```
[ 'E', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'E', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'E', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'E', 'r', 'i', 'c' ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1

```
var res = text.match(new RegExp(myName, 'g')).join('').split('');
```

## 2

```js
var text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Elic \
blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

var myName = "Eric";
var hits   = [];
var l      = 0;
var count  = 0;
var foundName = '';  

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  foundName = '';

  if (text[i] === "E") {
    for (var j = 0; j < myName.length; j++) {
      foundName += text[i + j];                
    }

    if (foundName === myName) {
      for (var k = 0; k < myName.length; k++) {
        hits.push(foundName[k]);                
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(hits);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need both of those internal `for` loops. What's happening when you `break`, you're breaking out of the innermost for loop but are still running the second for loop.

Try this instead of the two internal for loops: (replace the for loop that involves `j`)

```
for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    if (text[i + k] === myName[k]) {
        hits.push(text[i + k]); 
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well here, its not printing 'E',

Comment: [ 'r', 'i', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'c' ] is the output

Comment: @Vizkos how so? Indexing out of bounds in javascript would return `undefined`, which is not equal to any of the possible characters in `myName`.

Comment: Oh never mind, I see what you're saying. I wasn't sure whether OP meant to include partial renditions of his name (like extra 'E's) so I just gave the solution that I thought differed least from his provided code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do with the result but assuming you just want to test if the name is in a string the you use the `.indexOf()` method so:

```
var n = text.indexOf("Eric");
```

Then the result of `n` will display the first characters index position and if fails to find the matching word then it will return `-1`.

So then you add this to a simple test like:

```
if(text.indexOf("Eric") <0){
     \\doStuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using javascript [.indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) function.

```
text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Elic \
blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

if(text.indexOf('Eric') < 0 ){
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
```

Comment: you missed the point, he might be trying to find a name, but the o/p the question asks isn't the one you did :P

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ..

```
     text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Elic lah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

    var charFound=0;
    var myName = ['E' , 'r', 'i' ,'c'];
    var hits = [];
    var l=0;
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) 
    {
        if(text[i] === myName[charFound])
        {   
          charFound++;
        }
        else
        {
          continue;
          charFound=0;
        }
        if(charFound == 4)
        {
          for(var j = 0; j < 4;  j++)
          {
             hits.push(text[i-j]); 
            }
            charFound = 0;
        }
   }
   // Rearranging the hits counter to match the requirement
   for(var k = 0; k <hits.length/2; k++ )
   {
        var temp="";
        temp = hits[k];
        hits[k]= hits[hits.length-k-1];
        hits[hits.length-k-1] = temp;
   }
  alert(hits);
```